# PHP - Get mysqli data to display side by side with css

Tags: php, css, mysqli

I want this table of data to be displayed in 3 columns instead of 1 column as it's doing now; how would I do this with CSS ?

```html
    <?php
     echo "<table><tr><th>Tours</th></tr>";
     while($rowTours = $resultTours->fetch_assoc()){ 
       echo "<tr><td><h4>{$rowTours['Destination']}</h4>"; 
       echo "\r\n £ {$rowTours['Price']}\r\n";
       echo "\r\n{$rowTours['Description']}"; 
       echo "<img src=\"img/{$rowTours['destimg']}\" 
                  class =\" img-circle img-thumbnail\"> 
             </td></tr>";                  
            }
     echo "</table>";
   ?>
```

Comment: Add three more columns (td) in there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php
     echo "<table>
                 <TR>
                    <TH>Destination</TH> <TH>Price</TH> <TH>Description</TH>
                 </TR>";
     while($rowTours = $resultTours->fetch_assoc()){ 
       echo "<TR>
                <TD><h4>{$rowTours['Destination']}</h4>
                      <img src=\"img/{$rowTours['destimg']}\" 
                       class =\" img-circle img-thumbnail\"> 
          </TD> 
                <TD>£ {$rowTours['Price']}</TD>
                <TD>{$rowTours['Description']}</TD>
             </TR>";                  
            }
     echo "</table>";
   ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe to move tr tags outside the loop, where is table tag, like this?
tr is row, td is cell in row, and i guess that you have 3 results in loop, and you wanna each in one cell (column)?

```
  <?php
            echo "<table><tr><th>Tours</th></tr><tr>";
           while($rowTours = $resultTours->fetch_assoc()){ 


                echo "<td><h4>{$rowTours['Destination']}</h4>"; 
                echo "\r\n £ {$rowTours['Price']}\r\n";
                echo "\r\n{$rowTours['Description']}"; 
                echo "<img src=\"img/{$rowTours['destimg']}\" class =\" img-circle img-thumbnail\"> </td>";

            }
                echo "</tr></table>";

          ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
     echo "<table><tr><th>Tours</th></tr><tr>";
     while($rowTours = $resultTours->fetch_assoc()){ 

        echo "<td><h4>{$rowTours['Destination']}</h4></td>"; 
        echo "<td>£ {$rowTours['Price']}</td>";
        echo "<td><img src=\"img/{$rowTours['destimg']}\" class =\" img-circle img-thumbnail\"> </td>";
     }
     echo "</tr></table>";

?>
```